# Select Relationships from table as columns

Tags: sql, select, multiple-columns

I have an organization table with information about the organization and a table which stores the contacts within that organization. I want to create a query which will select an organization and all the phone numbers associated with their contacts in columns.

EX Org | Phone1 | Phone 2 | Phone 3

I have been looking around at pivot table selects and things like that but I have only seen information on how to select it in the same table not multiple tables.

I want to select it all in one row so I can have clean data for a custom excel sheet I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most performing way to do an unpivot on a large table (if you database does not support `unpivot`) is:

```
select org,
       (case when n.n = 1 then phone1
             when n.n = 2 then phone2
             when n.n = 3 then phone3
        end) as phone
from orgs o cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) n;
```

(Note:  in some databases you might need `from dual` for the `n` subqueries.)

You can also do this as a `union all`:

```
select org, phone1 from orgs union all
select org, phone2 from orgs union all
select org, phone3 from orgs;
```

The `union all` approach requires scanning the table three times, whereas the first approach will typically scan the data table only once.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to have it layout in the way you want seems like overkill but here goes some pseudo-code:

You're going to have to write some VBA.
First, write a query that gets every unique combination of phone number and org.
Second, set the active cell where you want to start.
Then iterate through that recordset and **for each** org and set the cell value to the org name.
Next iterate through and **for each** phone number with that org move the active cell to the right and make the cell value equal to the phone number.
Repeat until you reach the **count** of org instances then move back to the first cell and down a row.
Do this for every org not in your first column.